# A proof of $\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i{j \choose i}(j^n-i^n)^z=j!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm quite confused about how can this be possible in this sum.

let $j=nz$ and the sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i{j \choose i}(j^n-i^n)^z=j!$$

I would like to see proof of this sum, thank you.

Comment: See the second formula here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition You probably mean this with $n=k$ ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We seek to show that (here $j=nq$)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{j} (-1)^{k+j-q}
{j\choose k} (j^n - k^n)^q = j!$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{j} (-1)^{k+j-q} {j\choose k}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} j^{np} (-1)^{q-p} k^{j-np}
\\ = (-1)^{j} \sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} j^{np} (-1)^{p}
\sum_{k=0}^{j} (-1)^{k} {j\choose k} k^{j-np}.$$

Continuing,

$$(-1)^{j} \sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} j^{np} (-1)^{p}
\sum_{k=0}^{j} (-1)^{k} {j\choose k} (j-np)!
[z^{j-np}] \exp(kz)    
\\ = (-1)^{j} \sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} j^{np} (-1)^{p}
(j-np)! [z^{j-np}] (1-\exp(z))^{j}.$$

Now $1-\exp(z) = - z - \cdots$ and we have $[z^{j-np}] (1-\exp(z))^{j}
= 0$ when $1\le p\le q,$ hence

$$(-1)^{j} \sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} j^{np} (-1)^{p}
[[p=0]] (j-np)! [z^{j-np}] (1-\exp(z))^{j}
\\ = (-1)^{j} \sum_{p=0}^q [[p=0]] (j-np)! [z^{j-np}]
{q\choose p} j^{np} (-1)^{p}
(1-\exp(z))^{j}
\\ = (-1)^{j} j! [z^{j}] (1-\exp(z))^{j}
= j!$$

This is the claim.

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear correct.

If $z=0$
the left side is zero and
the right side is
$j!$.

Also,
$z$ and $n$ should be in the result.